# Strange issue with jQuery's slideUp/slideDown

Tags: javascript, jquery, slidedown, slideup

I use the following code on a website:

```
  // show tracks
  $('.content-playlist .track p').live('click', function() {
    var player_handle = $(this);
    $('.content-playlist .track .player').slideUp('slow', function() {
      player_handle.next().slideDown('slow');
    });
  });
```

Which should first closes any music players on the site (if any) and after that open the selected one.

Clicking the first track works as expected.

However I'm having a strange issue:

When clicking on the third track it opens, closes and opens again. (not what I want)

An example is online @: http://www.psykotaktyle.com/index.php?page=playlist

I just cannot find out what´s wrong with my code. Any help is much appreciated!

**EDIT**

Tested with Chrome (v13), IE9 and FF4

Comment: your code works as expected in chrome. test to see if it's not browser  compatibility issue

Comment: @gion: I'm currently using Chrome 13 to test. Since the latest Canary build (v15) has issues and jQuery doesn't work with it

Comment: @gion: Are you sure you have clicked the third track??? I've tested it with Chrome (v13), IE9 and FF4 and they all have this issue!

Comment: it works in firefox too:|, sty but i can't see a problem with your code

Comment: @gion: Did you click the 3rd track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/HR3EJ/)

```
$('.player').hide();
$('.content-playlist .track p').live('click', function() {
    $('.player:visible').slideToggle(600);
    $(this).next('.player').slideToggle(600);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like animation queuing as described at http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/01/quick-tip-prevent-animation-queue-buildup

Try:

```
$('.content-playlist .track .player').stop().slideUp('slow', function() {
      player_handle.next().stop().slideDown('slow');
    });
```

Comment: nopez problem still here. Also I don't think that can be in the case because (correct me if wrong) the callback only gets executed once the animation is finished.